# read xml in php

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I want to read the following structure in PHP.

```
<Listing>
<Unit_Type> 1 Bedroom </Unit_Type>
<Facilities>
<facility>Balcony</facility>
<facility>Basement parking</facility>
<facility>BBQ area</facility>
<facility>Built in wardrobes</facility>
<facility>Covered parking</facility>
</Facilities>
</Listing>
```

following is my code.

```
$feeds = new DOMDocument();
$feeds->load("propspace.xml"); 
$properties = $feeds->getElementsByTagName("Listing");

foreach( $properties as $property ){
$unittype_tag = $property->getElementsByTagName("Unit_Type");
$unit_type = $unittype_tag->item(0)->nodeValue;

 }
```

The number of `<facility>` tag can be variable.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Search for "DOMDocument DOMXPath".

Comment: Can't you simply use `$property->getElementsByTagName("Facilities")` and make a `foreach` on this?

Comment: Asif, you should make clear into which concrete problem you run. Your code does not look like if it would be broken. As it looks fine, it is not clear what you're asking about. It just works: http://eval.in/9576

Answer (score 1):

To read the facilities, just call `getElementsByTagName("facility")` on the `$property`:

```
$feeds = new DOMDocument();
$feeds->load("propspace.xml"); 
$properties = $feeds->getElementsByTagName("Listing");

foreach( $properties as $property ){
  $unittype_tag = $property->getElementsByTagName("Unit_Type");
  $unit_type = $unittype_tag->item(0)->nodeValue;

  foreach($property->getElementsByTagName("facility") as $f){
    echo $f->nodeValue . "\n";
  }
}
```

Outputs

> Balcony
>   Basement parking
>   BBQ area
>   Built in wardrobes
>   Covered parking

[Demo](http://codepad.org/q8vjigD5)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $xml = '
   <Listing>
      <Unit_Type> 1 Bedroom </Unit_Type>
      <Facilities>
         <facility>Balcony</facility>
         <facility>Basement parking</facility>
         <facility>BBQ area</facility>
         <facility>Built in wardrobes</facility>
         <facility>Covered parking</facility>
      </Facilities>
   </Listing>';

  $feeds = new DOMDocument();
  $feeds->loadXML($xml); 
  $properties = $feeds->getElementsByTagName("Listing");

  foreach( $properties as $property )
  {
    $unittype_tag = $property->getElementsByTagName("Unit_Type");
    $unit_type = $unittype_tag->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $Facilities = $property->getElementsByTagName("facility")
    foreach($Facilities as $facility)
    {
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($facility->nodeValue);
      echo "</pre>";
    }    
  }

?>
```